# What is the name of the App Launch event for Facebook Analytics?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-canvas

I'm trying to implement the new analytics for a Facebook game (using HTML/Javascript and Flash on Canvas, so there is no mobile version), but it seems that the documentation is incomplete. It says that there are 14 predefined events:

> "Events are one of **14** predefined events such as 'added to cart' in a
>   commerce app or 'level achieved' in a game"

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.AppEvents.LogEvent

> "The **fourteen** pre-defined events are: App Launch, Complete
>   Registration, Content View, Search, Rating, Tutorial Completed, Add to
>   Cart, Add to Wishlist, Initiated Checkout, Add Payment Info, Purchase,
>   Level Achieved, Achievement Unlocked, Spent Credits."

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/faq

However, on the reference page where all the events should be listed, the list is **only 12** items long, and there is no "App launch" event:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.AppEvents.LogEvent#events

Now, there are some sample event lists for some games, but they are very basic and they don't include the actual code: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/best-practices#casual
which recommends to use these events:

```
App Install
App Launch
Completed Registration
Completed Tutorial
Level Achieved
Achievement Unlocked
(...)
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
FB.AppEvents.activateApp()
```

**But is this event the equivalent of `App Install` or `App Launch`?**

Also, should I send this before the user accepts to share his basic info or after? I'm having so many questions because it's not clear what `activateApp()` does...

Here is some code for sending some other events that could be useful:

```
FB.AppEvents.logEvent(FB.AppEvents.EventNames.COMPLETED_REGISTRATION);

FB.AppEvents.logEvent(FB.AppEvents.EventNames.COMPLETED_TUTORIAL);

var params = {};
params[FB.AppEvents.ParameterNames.LEVEL] = '12'; //player level
FB.AppEvents.logEvent(
    FB.AppEvents.EventNames.ACHIEVED_LEVEL,
    null,  // numeric value for this event - in this case, none
    params
);
```

I still have more questions: how can I properly send the game version number (maybe with activateApp?) so I can create segments and cohorts later? Some example codes would be really appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

FB.AppEvents.activateApp() provides install and launch event functionality, which is why those two events are not enumerated as options in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.AppEvents.LogEvent#events. Activate app doesn't take a parameter. You might want to look at using a custom event to satisfy your use case.

Comment: I can confirm that activateApp() provides launch event functionality, but I am not sure about the install event functionality that you mention. This is what I have used in my code for Android: "AppEventsLogger.activateApp(getApplication());". When I go to check the event reports, App Launches is returning data, but App Installs is not. It gives me the impression that activateApp() is used to track App Launches, not App Installs. I do not know why at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/sdk#install-tracking they say that activateApp() is used to "enable install tracking".